# SAX parsing using XML file in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

```
<root>
        <subelement>
             <item></item>
              <valid></valid>
        </subelement>
        <subelement>
              <item></item>
             <valid></valid>
        </subelement>
        <valid></valid>
  </root>
```

In the above response i need to parse and get the subelement value to arraylist and get the root element "valid" tag value String ....How can i parse it.I have did sample but this kind of format is little bit confusing me.

Comment: if possible ask them to change the response like <root>
        <subelement>
             <item></item>
              <valid></valid>
        </subelement>
        <subelement>
              <item></item>
             <valid></valid>
        </subelement>
        
  </root>

Comment: @Sumant it's given from client side dude..Try to solve this issue yar.

Answer (score 1):

you can use defaulthandler for this work and write code same this for it

```
boolean subelement,item,valid;rootvalid;
@Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

if(localName.equal("subelement"))
subelement=true;
if(localName.equal("item"))
item=true;
if(subelement && localName.equal("valid"))
valid=true;
else if(localName.equal("valid"))
rootvalid=true;
}
 public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException 
    {
if(localName.equal("subelement"))
subelement=false;
if(localName.equal("item"))
item=false;
if(subelement && localName.equal("valid"))
valid=false;
else if(localName.equal("valid"))
rootvalid=false;
}
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
    {
if(item)
//add item to arraylist
if(valid)
//add valid to arraylist
if(validroot)
//save valid of root}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) Documantation and follwo this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/). It will surely help out.

Comment: Thanks for you reply dude.I have worked as like that responses but i don't know how to parse this kind of formats...